# How do I copy all feature attributes to a feature in a new layer?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to create a new layer in QGIS based on an existing layer. The new features should have all the attributes of the corresponding features in the original layer. I've been trying to use `outFeat.setAttributeMap(inFeat.attributeMap() )` similar to what Victor Olaya is doing at http://qgissextante.blogspot.de/2012/11/spliting-vector-layer.html, but all the attributes come out as NULL.

Could you tell me where the error is in my code?

```py
def test(outputFilename):
 layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
 provider = layer.dataProvider()
 fields = provider.fields()
 writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(outputFilename, "CP1250", fields, provider.geometryType(), provider.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
 inFeat = QgsFeature()
 outFeat = QgsFeature()
 inGeom = QgsGeometry()
 while provider.nextFeature(inFeat):
  point = inFeat.geometry().asPoint()
  inGeom = inFeat.geometry()
  outFeat.setGeometry(inFeat.geometry() )
  outFeat.setAttributeMap(inFeat.attributeMap() )
  writer.addFeature( outFeat )
 del writer
 newlayer = QgsVectorLayer(outputFilename, "Output", "ogr")
 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(newlayer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `provider.select()` method call.

```
provider.select(provider.attributeIndexes() )
while provider.nextFeature(inFeat):
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! That fixes it! (I had to add `provider.select( provider.attributeIndexes() )`, though, which makes sense when looking at [the docs](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#aed7343c5ccea4d4fe795159eb4268b96))

Comment: All good.  Just be aware that this has changed in the latest dev build so you will have to update it in 2.0